# Installation Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04.4 on Intel NUC 7i5BNH Failed with errno 5

Tags: system-installation, intel-nuc

**Problem**: During installation of Ubuntu 16.04.4 on an Intel NUC 7i5BNH, I get the error:

```
    [Errno 5] Input/output error 
    This is often due to faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, a faulty hard disk.
```

Installation medium: bootable USB stick. 
The error message is obviously nonsense, since the life "CD" works. Booting from the USB stick into Ubuntu 16.04.4 works. But when running the installation, the error occurs.

As I could solve the problem after many trials, I'd like to provide the solution.

**Answer/Solution**

*Short answer*: Ubuntu 16.04.5 works http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso

*Long answer*:

- 16.04 is installable, but the GUI is very slow and neither wifi nor ethernet works.
- 16.04.4 works as life "CD", but provides the error at installation.
- 18.04.1 works as life "CD", but provides the error at installation.
- linuxmint-19-cinnamon-64bit-v2.iso works as life "CD", but provides the error at installation.
- 16.04.5 works fine and is installable.

Oviously, to my understanding, Intel's NUC drivers are sometimes forgotten or are not properly included when creating a Ubuntu release. Maybe the RAM hardware and the disk hardware also affects the problem. So here is my hardware configuration:

- NUC 7i5BNH
- *RAM*: Crucial CT16G4SFD8213 16GB memory (DDR4, 2133 MT/s, PC4-17000, DRx8, SODIMM, 260-Pin)
- *Disk*: WD Black NVMe SSD 500 GB, M.2 2280 disk WDS500G2X0C